# update dropdown values based on another dropdown - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

Here is the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yugouodg/1/)

I have two dropdown items in my HTML.

`where from` and `where to`

You have to chose `where from` before the `where to` is filled with options.

The array containing the different places looks like this:

```
 var allCities = ["Napoli", "Palermo", "Cagliari", "Barcelona", "Malaga", "Rio de Janeiro"];
```

After `where from` is chosen, I want to update the values in `where to` with the items in the array that has an index higher than the one that was first chosen.

E.g. If I choose Cagliari as my `where from`.

My `where to` should display `Barcelona, Malaga, Rio de Janeiro`, but my `where to` dropdown never gets any values.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things,

First, you need to change the `$("#travel_from").on( "selectmenuchange", ...` to `$("#travel_from").on( "change", ...`

You'll also need to clear the `travel_to` cities each time you do this event, like so

```
$('#travel_to').find('option').remove();
```

If you want the `travel_to` dropdown to be disabled at first, you'll need to give the `select` the `disabled` property in your HTML, then remove it when you do the change event.

HTML

```
<select id="travel_to" disabled>
```

JS

```
$('#travel_to').prop('disabled', false);
```

That's it. This should be pretty much what you're looking for, here's a [complete fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ef492q5j/)